# Was Plan B in Interstellar carried out?

Tags: ending, interstellar

In *Interstellar*, it was proposed that if Plan A of evacuating the humans on Earth does not work out, they would have to colonize a new planet using the frozen human embryos. But since the evacuation was successful, was Edmund's planet finally colonised using the embryos or was it just Dr. Amelia Brand and CASE on Edmund's planet (and Cooper after them)?

Comment: "it was proposed that if Plan A of evacuating the humans on Earth does not work out" No, this plan was phony: ["Meanwhile, Murphy, now a scientist, has transmitted a message announcing Professor Brand has died. She has learned that Plan A, that required unattainable data from within a black hole, was never viable. Plan B was always Professor Brand's only option."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)#Plot) This is literally in the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the final shot of Brand, it seems clear that she has set up the nursery modules among her camp on Edmunds' planet. This element of 'Plan B' had been previously referenced while on Mann's planet prior to the revelation of his treachery [(Cooper: "We need to pick out a site. You don’t wanna move the module once we land it.").](http://www.raindance.org/wp-content/uploads/FLFinalSPv1.pdf)

So, as Brand is unaware of Cooper's survival and Murph's discovery of the 'theory of everything' (quantum relativity?), the closing shot suggests that she is proceeding with 'Plan B', as she is unaware of 'Plan A's' success and despite and/or possibly due to her isolation she does the most proactive thing possible - follow her duty with regards to her fertilizing the population bomb.