# How were both Plan A and Plan B supposed to work together?

Tags: interstellar

From what we see in the movie *Interstellar* and from [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97903/was-plan-b-in-interstellar-carried-out), it seems that both Plan A and Plan B were implemented.

Now, considering that humans who survived from Earth, would ultimately have to move from Cooper station (and other stations) to Edmunds' planet, won't this open up a whole new array of problems, such as, who owns the planet - the human survivors or the embryonic adults? Or maybe even, how would they mix with one another?

Also, I do not think that the creators of the plans (Dr. Brand and others) would have thought about this since one plan was simply a backup for the other.

Comment: No, one of the plans was a decoy, something for humanity to keep hope alive (as explained in one of the video chats). It is only after Cooper manages to communicate with his daughter that the phony plan becomes reality. As for "who owns the planet": the number of people involved would make it ridiculous for this to be an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight answer to your question of how plans A and B were *supposed* to work together is simply that **they never were**.

As you already said in your other question, *officially* plan B was just a fallback for plan A in case that didn't succeed. But even more so *inofficially* plan A was never expected to succeed at all. So no, **the creators of the plans have most probably *not* thought about the political and philosophical implications** of mixing artificially born natives and naturally born colonists into a single society, not that such considerations would have been of a particularly high priority anyway.

But I'm afraid this also is all there is to answer here. If your further question is how this new society *would* pan out given that it *has* to now, this is beyond the point of the film's story, the information available to us, and thus the site's scope. We can't really speculate about how any government or society on this new colony would work, let alone the broader philosophical considerations of this issue.

But yes, colonizing a new world and/or large-scale artificial breeding of humans most certainly poses a lot of problems, **none of which either the film or its characters concerned themselves with**, though.

Comment: It's also important to note that now plan A happens to have succeeded, they don't specifically _need_ the other planets anymore, as evidenced by Cooper Station.